# HubbleStack on Windows 10 top.nova file needed for Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, security, content-security-policy

ADMINS: Can we please start a HubbleStack page?

We are trying to get HubbleStack 2.4.7 to run on Windows 10.
Are there any users on board who are familiar enough to help a person get it running?

Basically, we (think) apparently do not have a top.nova with a Windows 10 section in it.

test.ping runs hubble.audit and hubble.top return {}

We can get it to run (apparently) incorrect Windows with errors.

Is there documentation on how to create a match field for Windows 10 Enterprise? (Not sure how to use the osquery information to build the string Nova expects to see from the OS.)

Is there documentation as to how to build a CIS profile for Windows 10?

I have no experience in translating Linux speak into Windows, and my Python experience isn't helping with this very advanced code.

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't have pages "dedicated" to specific applications or libraries.

Comment: I can appreciate that. Edited to add the security and Content security Tags. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's very doubtful...at best, you can create a new "hubblestack" tag, and use on specific questions you have.

Comment: When I get the "reputation" level...